# List getting created incorrectly

Tags: python

I am trying to create a list based on the input below, and I don't see the expected output. Can anyone suggest where am I going wrong?

**INPUT:**

```
CR  FA  CL  Title
409452  WLAN    656885  Age out RSSI values from buffer in Beacon miss scenario
415560  WLAN    656886  To Record SMD Event Logging
```

I want an OUTPUT like

```
[['CR', 'FA', 'CL', 'TITLE'], ['409452', 'WLAN', '656885', 'Age out RSSI values from buffer in Beacon miss scenario'], ['415560', 'WLAN', '656886','To Record SMD Event Logging']]
```

But i see its getting created like

```
[['CR', 'FA', 'CL', 'TITLE'], ['', '409452', 'WLAN', '656885\tAge out RSSI values from buffer in Beacon miss scenario'], ['', '415560', 'WLAN', '656886\tTo Record SMD Event Logging']]
```

Python code

```
 for i in info.splitlines():
    index = re.split(r'\W+',i,3)
    CRlist.append(index)
```

Comment: Are you sure there's no extra whitespace at the start of each line (e.g., some extra `\r`s lying around because you parsed another platform's text file without universal-newlines mode)? Because that's exactly what you would see in that case.

Comment: there might be extra whilespaces,trailing \r,\n,I want to strip of all of them

Comment: i copy your input to a file and tested your code.it is ok.all i can guess is platform difference issue.

Comment: @oyss: From the OP's comments, I think the difference is that his actual input file has extraneous (possibly invisible) whitespace characters that got lost in the copy/paste to SO. Unless he uploads the input file somewhere we can look it over, that's still just a guess—although the fact that my suggestion fixed the problem is pretty good evidence that it's a correct guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output you're getting is exactly what you'd expect if there were extra whitespace at the start of each line but the first.

One common reason for this is that you've tried parsing files with the wrong line endings, without using universal-newlines mode, and just gotten things hopelessly confused.

For example, these two lines may look identical in your text editor:

```
409452  WLAN    656885  Age out RSSI values from buffer in Beacon miss scenario
\r409452  WLAN    656885  Age out RSSI values from buffer in Beacon miss scenario
```

But your `re.split` will do very different things with them:

```
['409452', 'WLAN', '656885', 'Age out RSSI values from buffer in Beacon miss scenario']
['', '409452', 'WLAN', '656885\tAge out RSSI values from buffer in Beacon miss scenario']
```

The solution is to strip off the excess whitespace. You can try to write a more complicated regexp, or just do `re.split(r'\W+', s.lstrip(), 3)`.

Since you mentioned wanting to strip trailing whitespace as well, use `strip` instead of `lstrip`: `re.split(r'\W+', s.strip(), 3)`.

But I'm not sure why you're using regexp in the first place, when you could just do `s.strip().split(None, 3)`.

Answer (score 1):

I have a feeling you should rather be using `csv` module, but here is a non-regex solution:

```
>>> s = '''CR  FA  CL  Title
... 409452  WLAN    656885  Age out RSSI values from buffer in Beacon miss scenario
... 415560  WLAN    656886  To Record SMD Event Logging'''
>>> [x.strip().split(None, 3) for x in s.splitlines()]
[['CR', 'FA', 'CL', 'Title'], ['409452', 'WLAN', '656885', 'Age out RSSI values from buffer in Beacon miss scenario'], ['415560', 'WLAN', '656886', 'To Record SMD Event Logging']]
```

Comment: This won't solve his problem. It works in exactly the same cases as his original code. And it has the side effect of converting all whitespace in column 4 into single spaces.

Comment: How does it convert whitespace in column 4 to spaces?

Comment: The current version doesn't, but the previous version did. (Or possibly the different answer in the same position that got deleted and replaced with yours? Not sure…) It did `split()`, and then recombined the last column with `' '.join(x[3])`.

Comment: @wim: When using `.split()` (or `.split(None, n)`), you don't need to `.strip()` the string first. That's needed only when using `.split(' ')` (or `.split(' ', n)`) and the string might have leading or trailing spaces.

Comment: @MRAB are you sure about that?  `'spam and eggs '.split(None, 2)` leaves the trailing whitespace in the output on my version of python.

Comment: @wim: You're correct, although that's because you're not splitting to the end so the trailing spaces remain (if you see what I mean). The leading spaces, however, _are_ removed.

Comment: The OP did specifically mention in a comment that "there might be extra whilespaces,trailing \r,\n,I want to strip of all of them", so the `strip()` (or `rstrip()`) is necessary here. (PS, @wim, I think the downvote has been here since yesterday, probably someone drive-by voting based on my comment to your original version, not downvoting the current working version. It's frustrating when people do that, because they never come back.)

Answer (score 0):

if you have \t as separator than you can use this(note that you can use strip and check if item.strip() to check whether is the empty entry or not and skip it if so):

```
info = """
          CR  FA  CL  Title
          409452  WLAN    656885  Age out RSSI values from buffer in Beacon miss scenario
          415560  WLAN    656886  To Record SMD Event Logging
       """
[[x.strip() for x in row.split('\t') if x.strip()] for row in info.split('\n')]
```

if you have multiple spaces beetween columns you can try ti use this:

```
[[x.strip() for x in row.split('  ') if x.strip()] for row in info.split('\n')]
```

or combined:

```
[[x.strip() for x in row.replace('\t', '  ').split('  ') if x.strip()] for row in info.split('\n')]
```

and finally using split(None, 3):

```
[row.split(None, 3) for row in info.split('\n')]
```

Comment: Why not just `split(None)`, which splits on any whitespace, which is what he obviously wants (given the use of `r'\W'`)? Meanwhile, you're rewriting the part of his code that's already working. You _do_ have the probably fix in there (the `strip()`), but tossed in without comment, so he won't be able to figure out that's what actually matters.

Comment: Let me disagree - i was not able to figure out that he wants to split on each space, bcoz the last column contains a sentence with a spaces in it and he wants to have it whole - isn't he? As well as strip will not eliminate his problem with tabulars.

Comment: He wants to split on each whitespace, but only on the first three of them. If you read his regexp, and his expected output, there's nothing else it could possibly mean. And I'm not sure what "problem with tabulars" you're talking about; `strip` will fix the only problem his code actually has.

Comment: @abarnet - sure, thank you, added a comment to let him know about strip using and it's effect. It just the solution that working without regex and nothing more - please be bear with me - i simply want to give him an option to solve. +1 to your solution like more apropriate answer

Comment: Actually, I like your answer because it's a good idea to teach him how to write pythonic code than to just fix trivial errors for him, and I only did that in a parenthetical aside, while your answer makes it central. But your answer doesn't actually do the same thing he seems to be trying to do—it doesn't handle all whitespace, it doesn't ignore whitespace after the third split, etc. If you just used `split(None, 3)` it would be the best way to write what he wants to do (better than my answer, which is just a minor change to his original code).